# parsing a custom XML file with NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, ios, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse this custom XML file with NSXMLParser.  I'm new to parsing XML, so I apologize if this is a simple question.  But, here is a sample of this XML file:

```
<recordset>
<record>
<LIST_BILL_CIM>05645458</LIST_BILL_CIM>
<BILLPRINT_LVL_CIM>05645458</BILLPRINT_LVL_CIM>
<OWNING_CARRIER>FE</OWNING_CARRIER>
</record>
</recordset>
```

Here is the method that's doing the parsing.  I'm able to see the elementName, but unsure how to access the data.  Any help is appreciated!  Thanks!

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"LIST_BILL_CIM"]) {
    NSLog(@"LIST_BILL_CIM = %@", [attributeDict objectForKey:0]);
}
}
```

Comment: There are many more pieces than this one method. The process is fully detailed here along with example code: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html

Comment: I didn't post the other pieces because I am getting to the data just fine, but can't seem to access the data within <LIST_BILL_CIM>DATA HERE</LIST_BILL_CIM>.  I am seeing all of the element names (which shows LIST_BILL_CIM as one of the element names) though.

Comment: But, thanks for the direction ... checking out those docs now.

Comment: Ah, you're right ... I was missing:

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{
if(!currentElementValue) {
    currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
}
else 
{
    [currentElementValue appendString:string];
}
```

}

// Note: don't forget to release or nil currentElement in didEndElement